# Path connected set of matrices?

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices, path-connected

Consider the collection of $n$ by $n$ matrices
$$S=\{ A: A_{ij}\le0,\quad (-1)^{c_i}\det A(P_i;Q_i)<0 \quad \text{for} \quad i=1,\ldots, k\}$$
where $c_i\in \{0,1\}$, $P_i$ and $Q_i$ are disjoint index sets, and $A(P_i;Q_i)$ is the submatrix formed by taking just the rows $P_i$ and columns $Q_i$ of $A$.

What kind of conditions on $S$ would be natural to add to guarantee that $S$ is path connected? Also what areas of mathematics are useful in trying to answer these types of path connected questions?

Comment: Set of non-positive matrices in general position. I would look at realisable oriented matroids. The chapter in http://www.booktopia.com.au/oriented-matroids-gunter-m-ziegler/prod9780521777506.html?source=pla&gclid=CjwKEAjwqJ67BRCzzJ7Hy-LYlFYSJABwp9PGDt9d5J3NHVBeelTlzJdpGDYx688RRS6_6SUJJekuNBoCSIfw_wcB addresses these things